# How to let child toolbar stay on top of the parent Panel when scrolled?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, scroll, panel

I have a drawing program written in C# over here, and I have a Panel(just an ordinary Panel) inside it. I created a toolbar inside the Panel as a child control, so the user can control the properties of the shapes in this toolbar. But when the Panel was scrolled a certain amount, the toolbar will be scrolled outside of view (FYI the toolbar was docked or anchored to the top of the Panel). So can you please tell me how to let the toolbar stay in view when the Panel was scrolled, because we want the users to edit a shape wherever they are, right?

Comment: The toolbar has to be outside the scrolling panel.

Comment: I want the toolbar to be beside the panel, and I could think of no other way than to make the toolbar as the child control.

Comment: That's fine.  Add another panel below the toolbar that is the scrolling content.

Comment: What does that suppose to mean?

Comment: Why is moving the toolbar above the scrolling panel a problem?

Comment: Because the toolbars are contextual: when a shape is selected, a toolbar appears, when no shapes are selected, the other toolbar appears

Comment: That toolbar does not have to be inside the panel to do that.  Post some code how you are switching toolbars or something.  Your question did not mention anything about multiple toolbars.